# How to create, register and enable an index in Janusgraph?

Tags: cassandra, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph

I want to create an index to find a vertex by label and a property value.

I saw from documentation that i have to Install->Register->Enable the index, but somehow i can't get it to be Register and Enabled.

1. Install

```java
JanusGraph graph_joy = JanusGraphFactory
  .open("/home/white/IdeaProjects/squery-gremlin/conf/janusgraph.properties");

JanusGraphManagement mgmt = graph_joy.openManagement();
mgmt.buildIndex("indexID_05", Vertex.class)
     .indexOnly(mgmt.getVertexLabel("user"))
     .addKey(mgmt.getPropertyKey("userid")).buildCompositeIndex();

mgmt.commit();   
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph_joy,"indexID_05").call();
```

```
Graph Index | Type        | Unique    | Backing        | Key:           Status |
indexID_05  | Composite   | false     | internalindex  | userid:     INSTALLED |
```

2. Register? Enable?

```java
mgmt = graph_joy.openManagement();
ManagementSystem.awaitGraphIndexStatus(graph_joy,"indexID_05").call();
mgmt.updateIndex(mgmt.getGraphIndex("indexID_05"), SchemaAction.REGISTER_INDEX).get();
mgmt.commit();
```

Didn't work, i get Some key(s) on index indexID_05 do not currently have status(es) [REGISTERED]: userid=INSTALLED, and then timeout i see in the logs.
If someone can give a simple example of how to install->register->enable an index it will help i am stuck.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Creating property keys and indexes in the same transaction solved my issue. The index moved to ENABLED state without the need of manually changing the states using `mgmt.updateIndex()`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).